# How can I calculate new analogous color gradients, using a color ramp as defined by a triple of RGB values?

Tags: css, math, colors, gradient, background-color

Given a set of 3 colors, keeping the same ratios, but starting with a new color, generate the next two.

For example, the following is a pleasing blue gradient:

`rgb(172, 228, 248)` - Start

`rgb(108, 205, 243)` - Finish

`rgb(121, 181, 203)` - Border

I need to create a series of 10 similar gradients starting from different colors.  I'd like the gradients to maintain the same light-to-dark ratios.

So, given the color: `rgb(254, 218, 113)` (yellow), how can I calculate the end and border colors with the same ratios as above?

Comment: Thanks for helping me find the words @fish2000!

Comment: My pleasure, sir. I appreciate the opportunity to use my degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my try: suppose your initial three colors are:

```
rgb(a1, b1, c1) --> Start
rgb(a2, b2, c2) --> Finish
rgb(a3, b3, c3) --> Border
```

And suppose the color which you'd like to calculate the analogous pattern on is `rgb(x1, y1, z1)`. The other two components are calculated like this:

```
x2 = (a2 / a1) * x1, y2 = (b2 / b1) * y1, z2 = (c2 / c1) * z1
x3 = (a3 / a2) * x2, y3 = (b3 / b2) * y2, z3 = (c3 / c2) * z2
```

And thus your resulting colors are `rgb(x2, y2, z2)` and `rgb(x3, y3, z3)`.

Here's the result of applying the method above on your example color (`rgb(254, 218, 113)`):

[image]

The two resulting colors are `rgb(159, 196, 110)` and `rgb(178, 173, 92)` (note that they're rounded down to integers/whole numbers).

I hope that helped in any manner!

Comment: Hmm... If that's the same relationship as the first set, that's not very pretty.  Perhaps I need to reconsider how gradients should work.  I would have expected the finish to be a darker version of the start.  And the border to be a shade even darker than the finish. Something closer to rgb(254,186,72) and rgb(222,169,79).  Instead it moved to a green hue.

Comment: @Ryan So you want the gradient components to differ in lighting only?

Comment: I'm not sure how to describe it accurately.  I have a blue div with the gradient mentioned above in the question.  Now I'd like a yellow one.  And a red one. (and a dozen more)  But I want them all to look like they are part of the same family.  I can do this in photoshop by visiting the "hue & saturation" panel and dragging sliders.  But how can I do this programmatically?

Comment: how would you change your answer if it had to do only with lighting?

Comment: @Ryan You'd convert the RGB colors to HSL, and then manipulate the L (lighting) component only, in the same mechanism of analogizing proportions.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need but I'm not understanding how you get the resulting values from `rgb(254, 218, 113)`. Could you explain to me which values belong to which variable in the formula you use? For instance `x2 = (a2 / a1) * x1`. Which is x? Which is a? Which is y? z? etc.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A non-algorithmical solution (read: manual) in case you don't find something more interesting:

http://colorschemedesigner.com/

or http://kuler.adobe.com

Your colors have an advantage: They are all in the same "line", so fairly similar to the automatic values you can get using the monochromatic or complementary functions:

[image]

They should be (in theory) an easy way to calculate, since they are in a line and will keep the same distance, but because I don't know how it's done here's how you can do it manually (kuler uses RGB as well as HEX and other formats).